# How can I add an option to the ellipsis or right-click of an Azure DevOps work item (like a User Story)?

Tags: azure-devops

I saw an two-year-old question on SO about it, but nothing recent.  When I look at a card on the board, User Story, Task, etc., I have an ellipsis.  How can I add to the menu when it pops up or from a right-click menu.  Is that possible with Visual Studio or somewhere in the Azure DevOps admin?

Answer (score 1):

There’re many work items extensions in marketplace:[Extensions for Visual Studio family of products](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/azuredevops) .

You can install extension that’s related to work items in your DevOps and option will be added to the menu automatically.

For example, install extension  `Open in Excel` and you’ll see the option `open in excel` in your menu.

[image: open in excel]

I recommend you to search extension that meets your needs in marketplace. If there's no appropriate extension, you can develop by yourself. please refer to doc: [develop a web extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops)

And you can describe what function you want to add to option, i can help you to search it in marketplace.

Comment: @learntofix Hi, Does it give you some hep?